# dispatch_semaphore_signal never being executed because of the wait

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to take two pictures and want them to run in order. The method for capturing pictures is done using a method that runs asynchronously. I currently use semaphores to try to synchronize this, but it stops the program from running. I believe this is because the completionHandler is run on the same thread, and since the thread is locked, it can't execute to free the semaphore. 
Here is my current code:

```
    camera_sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);


    [photoOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         [flash turnOffFlash];//turning off flash for second picture
        //perform needed work

         dispatch_semaphore_signal(camera_sema);
     }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(camera_sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Is there a way I can use dispatch_async for this case or a way to run the completionHandler on another background thread so it is able to execute?

UPDATE 1:
This works but not sure if its the best way to do it.

```
-(void*)method: (int) iteration {
[photoOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         [flash turnOffFlash];//turning off flash for second picture
        //perform needed work
        //base case
        [method: iteration-1];

     }];
}
```

So basically I call the method recursively to ensure that it only repeats once the callback has been reached. It will essentially run an async task synchronously. Unfortunately, for the final design, I need to be able to run it infinitely. Doing this recursively will fail. Please let me know if there is better way to do this.

Comment: What code comes after the wait? Why not just put that code in the completion handler? (I.e. don't use a semaphore at all.) If that code needs to run on the main thread, dispatch it to the main queue in the completion handler.

Comment: I want to essentially loop this action. So this whole block of code that I have above should be run in a function that gets called for n number of times, but i want it to wait for the callback to be completed before rerunning the function for the next iterations. I currently have a solution where I am calling it recursively inside the callback. It works but I am not sure if thats the best solution.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfectly sensible solution. I presume you'll actually want some sort of termination condition, like when `iteration` reaches 0 or whatever.

Comment: Hey Ken, I want to be able to run this infinitely, do you know how I would be able to run this without the stack overflowing? Essentially keep capturing two images, process them and display, and repeat the whole process like a video capture.

Comment: This is not normal recursion. It should not overflow the stack. The asynchronous call returns immediately and your code which calls it is free to return back up to the main event loop or whatever, too. The block at that point is just a data object that's being held internally by the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` object. At some point in the future, it will call the block, which will call your method, but that's not within/under the stack frame of your earlier call.

Comment: It may not be a stack overflow, but after about 30-40 takes, the app just crashes with no error logs. Any guesses to whats happening?

Comment: It seems that the crash log for it indicates that the watchdog timer times out since everything is continuously being run on main queue, OS may think the app is frozen and crashes the app.

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question for the new issue and show the **real** code as well as the crash report.

Comment: Thanks I did that! heres the link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056179/recursive-callback-call-crashing-app-after-some-iterations-watchdog-error-ios